# How do i fill datagrid one row at a time from database using async await

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

Is there a possible way I could fill/populate datagridview with values/rows one at a time. I have tried this code but it shows all the data from the database all at once, what i want is that it would show the rows 1 at a time with a delay of lets say 500 millisecond before the next row appear. Sorry im new to c#, its only my third month learning c#, i would appriciate any help i could get. thank you.

```
  private async void button_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var connection = @"Data Source=LAPTOP-C1P6RQIA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBTest;Integrated Security=True";
        var command = @"SELECT * FROM Costumers";
        var data = await LoadData(command, connection);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }

  public async Task<DataTable> LoadData(string connection, string command)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        using (var adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(connection, command))
            await Task.Run(() => adapt.Fill(dt));
        return dt;
    }
```

This post is edited

Comment: Can you explain a little more? it would be better if you would give a simple code example that does what you expect (without async await)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, here's an example matching your request.

1. Place a DataGridView and a Button in your form's designer.
2. Add this code to your form's code:

   ```
    private async Task PopulateGrid()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Number");
        dt.Columns.Add("Time");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        for (var rowNumber = 1; rowNumber <= 20; rowNumber++)
        {
            var newRow = dt.NewRow();
            newRow["Number"] = rowNumber.ToString();
            newRow["Time"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
   ```
3. On your Button's click event, call function "PopulateGrid", like this:

   ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateGrid();
    }
   ```